# The Callback URL or Verify Token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, lets-encrypt, facebook-messenger-bot

I have been following the facebook bot setup guide and have setup a callback url that is running on an EC2 instance.

I am getting an error (see title of this) when trying to validate the callback url and verify token.

https://360.finance:1337/webhook is my webhook and the verify token is the same in my environment variable and in my facebook setting.

I set up SSL using LetsEncrypt and from what I can tell, the SSL is not showing as self signed so it looks to be working correctly (please note I'm new to all of this)

Checked at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=360.finance&hideResults=on and all looks correct.

I have also included the facebook page token as an environment variable and included in my index.js file

I have tested netcat / telnet into that port on my ec2 ip and it is succeeding

Comment: For anyone with the same challenge.  The fix was to set express.js up as https.  The facebook bot article doesn't mention this in the setup.

Comment: I have the same problem. Based on what logged in my server, it even didn't call my url. But when I test my url, it works in browser.

Answer (score 12):

You must return an http response of the hub.challenge token as a plain text.

Comment: Why they doesn't mention that clearly?!

Comment: The call from verify webhook even not reach my website. My url webhook url works fine in browser. The only think I suspect is I'm using the self-signed certificate. Is this the cause?

Answer (score 6):

We need to update the following on Facebook app settings page before adding The Callback URL or Verify Token.

1. Privacy Policy URL
2. Category
3. App Icon (1024*1024)

Its weird that facebook doesn't point our exact error.

Comment: I update all 3. Still facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `ngrok` or `localtunnel`.
I tried both, with no luck.

If you really want your local dev server to authenticate - you can port forward over ssh to your public faced server.

`ssh -R 4000:localhost:4000 root@your-server-ip`

This way you can setup nginx to reverse proxy 443 to 4000 and handle ssl with `certbot`

sample config for nginx reverse proxy (before running `certbot`)

```
server {
    server_name my-own-domain;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    listen 80;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
  }
}
```

So you "only" need:

- Your own domain
- Your own server
- nginx
- certbot
- SSH Server

And now you have your own private `ngrok` replacement

Comment: Why would they deny ngrok? Such a bad dev experience

Comment: No idea. It feels like they want to raise the bar and let only medium to large enterprise to use the API.

Answer (score 1):

check you callback server, if it is running or not ?

the callback and token comes from your server.

Answer (score 1):

For python users you need to use a dot not underscore. I don't get it when I use the underscore version Facebook API cant access `challenge` but when I replicate the same GET request with postman I can access the `challenge`.

```
# Wrong way
challenge = request.GET['hub_challenge']

# Right way
challenge = request.GET['hub.challenge']
return HttpResponse(challenge)
```

Answer (score 0):

After 2-3 hour debugging, my case was returning "\"1412656657\"" instead of "1412656657".

Fixed with returning the value inside Content()

```
public ContentResult Get()
{
    // validate token
    // get hub.challenge from query string
    var hubChallenge = Request.Query["hub.challenge"];
  
    return Content(hubChallenge, "text/plain");
}
```