# I created a controller in spring boot and used ngrok to make it public to configure Whatsapp's Cloud API but Whatsapp does not even hits my controller

Tags: java, whatsapp

This is how my spring boot controller looks like:

```
@RestController
public class WhatsappController {
    private final String VERIFICATION_TOKEN = "12345";

    @GetMapping("/webhook")
    public ResponseEntity<String> verifyWebhook(@RequestParam("hub.mode") String mode,
                                                @RequestParam("hub.challenge") String challenge,
                                                @RequestParam("hub.verify_token") String token) {
        if (mode.equals("subscribe") && token.equals(VERIFICATION_TOKEN)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(challenge, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Verification token or mode mismatch", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I configure ngrok URL with Whatsapp it says:

> The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Callback URL or Verify Token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544871/the-callback-url-or-verify-token-couldnt-be-validated-please-verify-the-provid)

Comment: Thanks for sharing but it does not.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by deploying my code to on AWS with an actual https URL. The issue was because of ngrok.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/webhook", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> verifyToken(@RequestParam("hub.mode") String mode,
                                     @RequestParam("hub.challenge") String challenge,
                                     @RequestParam("hub.verify_token") String token) {
    String verify_token = "token_webhook";
    if (mode.equals("subscribe") && token.equals(verify_token)) {
        System.out.println("WEBHOOK_VERIFIED");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(challenge, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more explanation why this code would improve the situation would be nice?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ngrok try https url provided by them.
[image]