# Failed to validate the WhatsApp cloud api webhook url callback in Strapi

Tags: javascript, strapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I deployed a Strapi project and run it through `pm2` and `nginx`. I have a webhook api in `https://zeusoftware.online/api/webhook`. Here is my code for verify the webhook, I didn't implement the token, challenge and mode logic yet.

#### Controller

```
module.exports = {
  verifyAction: async (ctx, next) => {
    console.log(ctx.request.body)
    try {
      ctx.body = 'ok';
    } catch (err) {
      ctx.body = err;
    }
  }
};
```

#### Route

```
module.exports = {
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/webhook',
      handler: 'webhook.verifyAction', 
    }
  ],
};
```

When I call this in my browser, it returns `ok`. But when I goto FB to config the **Webhook**. It always return the follow error:

> The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later.

I know I haven't implemented the logic yet. But my question is why the request even doesn't reach my application. I debug this through a `console.log`. (When I run in browser, the `console.log` works).

I can't find any document about how FB verify this webhook callback API. Any idea?

Found the follow related link. But it doesn't solve my issue.

[The Callback URL or Verify Token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544871/the-callback-url-or-verify-token-couldnt-be-validated-please-verify-the-provid)

Comment: It's working after I installed a new ssl cert through `certbot`. It proves the issue was caused by the self-signed certificate. The FB dashboard may verify if the certificate is valid.